# Simulating a Parallel Code

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, hpc

I had an idea for an asynchronous parallel program for a data science application. Considering a shared-memory system with one "master" and 20 "slaves". It would have a matrix at the master node; the slaves would read the value of the matrix, do some operations using random numbers and the return value would modify some elements of the matrix (asynchronously, allowing for overwrites; i.e. the slave who came 2nd could overwrite some of the work done by the slave who came 1st).

I know this can be done in `pthreads` but I didn't want to spend energy coding it up before having some prototype.

I wrote a parallel program simulator in MATLAB which:

- One-at-a-time and sequentially, does the operation which the slave would do and records the time. Store that in a vector called NEXT_EVENT_TIME_ARRAY.
- Adds an artificial delay to that time
  (= how_many_procs * BANDWIDTH_CONSTANT * size_of_M_in_megabytes)
- Set CURRENT_TIME = 0

Now, we loop:

- Picks the slave with minimum time as the one that "finished first in parallel"
- Set the value of CURRENT_TIME as CURRENT_TIME + this (minimum) time.
- This slave is then asked to do the same operation again with the updated matrix (the return value would change because the process involves random numbers).
- Record the time needed for the slave to finish and update the corresponding
  element of NEXT_EVENT_TIME_ARRAY to be CURRENT_TIME + time the slave took
  to finish computation with new value of M.
- Loop for a few iterations!

I will pick the BANDWIDTH_CONSTANT to match my computer. 
Is this is a reasonable model to get a proof-of-concept whether my algorithm will work in the asynchronous setting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what is the point of your simulator here, so I'm not sure the flaw I'll point is an issue for you, but the way I see it, your `BANDWIDTH_CONSTANT` is supposedly representing the memory bandwidth available on your computer, right?

If so, the trouble is that, since this bandwidth is a global resource to be shared among all the threads and processes running concurrently on your machine, the actual behaviour of your "slaves" is very likely to differ depending on they have dedicated access to this resource (sequential mode), or if they have to share it with other slaves (parallel mode)...

A good way to evaluate the impact of this sharing would be to run several independent sequential versions of your code concurrently on the same machine, and to record the performance impact this concurrency has compared to running one single job... This way, you should be able to better take into account this element into your model (although again I'm not sure this was an essential part of your simulator in the first place).